YouTube Data API for iOS application is not functioning, why?
I had been using the YouTube Data APIv3 to allow users to watch Kamala's most recent videos from within the app. It has already received a couple hundred downloads. It (being the video view) no longer functions as expected. It is in a state of "endless loading" now. Furthermore, when I view my API Dashboard it is as though I never used the API to begin with. I have an API key coupled with the channelID. Would anyone know what might be the issue?
Additional reading:
I do not build applications unless they are free of errors, meaning there are no errors (per se) in the code. It is a pretty simple view. The entire application is written in Swift/SwiftUI. I am in school for CompSci and this is my second application. I volunteer and I made this app for that. You know: "there's an app for that." Thanks in advance.
Respectfully,
Erica
I tried to launch the app as per usual. I expected to watch her most recent speech, but the video view would not load. There is nothing that I can do except rewrite the view using a deprecated version of WebKit.
This is the code in its entirety:
import AVKit
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Videos: View {
    @State private var videos: [Video] = []
    @State private var isLoading = true
    @State private var selectedVideo: Video?
    private let apiKey = "myAPIkey"
    private let channelId = "channelIdFromWhichIFetchVideos"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                if isLoading {
                    ProgressView("Loading...")
                } else {
                    List(videos.prefix(8)) { video in
                        VideoRow(video: video)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedVideo = video // Set the selected video when tapped
                            }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Recent Videos")
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: fetchVideos)
            .sheet(item: $selectedVideo) { video in
                VideoPlayerView(videoURL: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(video.id)")!)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedVideo) { video in
                VideoPlayerView(videoURL: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(video.id)")!)
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchVideos() {
        let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=\(apiKey)&channelId=\(channelId)&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=8"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching videos: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("JSON Response: \(jsonString)")
            }
            
            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(YouTubeResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.videos = decodedResponse.items.compactMap { Video(id: $0.id.videoId, title: $0.snippet.title, thumbnail: $0.snippet.thumbnails.default.url) }
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct VideoRow: View {
    var video: Video

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: video.thumbnail)) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 75)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(video.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .lineLimit(2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    var videoURL: URL
    
    var body: some View {
        WebView1(url: videoURL)
            .navigationTitle("Video Player")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct WebView1: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}

struct YouTubeResponse: Codable {
    let items: [VideoItem]
}

struct VideoItem: Codable {
    let id: VideoID
    let snippet: Snippet
}

struct VideoID: Codable {
    let videoId: String
}

struct Snippet: Codable {
    let title: String
    let thumbnails: Thumbnails
}

struct Thumbnails: Codable {
    let `default`: ThumbnailDetails
}

struct ThumbnailDetails: Codable {
    let url: String
}

struct Video: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let thumbnail: String
}

#Preview {
    Videos()
}

